# Spacing issue in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, gridbaglayout

Please have a look at the following code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestForm extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel heightLabel, weightLabel, waistLabel, neckLabel, hipsLabel,bfPercentageLabel;

    private JTextField heightTxt, weightTxt, waistTxt, neckTxt, hipsTxt;

    private JPanel centerPanel;


      public TestForm()
      {
        //Declaring instance variables  
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height: ");
        weightLabel = new JLabel("Weight: ");
        waistLabel = new JLabel("Waist: ");
        neckLabel = new JLabel("Neck: ");
        hipsLabel = new JLabel("Hips: ");        
        bfPercentageLabel = new JLabel("The Orginal Test Score Is: ");


        heightTxt = new JTextField(7);
        weightTxt = new JTextField(7);
        waistTxt = new JTextField(7);
        neckTxt = new JTextField(7);
        hipsTxt = new JTextField(7);



        this.add(createCenterPanel(),"Center");
        this.add(new JPanel(),"West");
        this.add(new JPanel(),"East");
        this.setTitle("The Test Form");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    private JPanel createCenterPanel()
    {
        centerPanel = new JPanel();

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        centerPanel.setLayout(gbl);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(heightLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(heightTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(weightLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,-10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(weightTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(waistLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(waistTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(neckLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,-10,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(neckTxt,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,7,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(hipsLabel,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,5,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(hipsTxt,gbc);



        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(50,0,0,0);
        centerPanel.add(bfPercentageLabel,gbc);



        centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("The Testing Form"));

        centerPanel.setPreferredSize(centerPanel.getPreferredSize());
        centerPanel.validate();

        return centerPanel;

    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            new TestForm();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this program I get the following.

[image: This is what I get]

In there, you can see the distance between `heightLabel` and `heightTxt`. And `waistLabel` and `waistTxt`. This MASSIVE gap is because of the JLabel `bfPercentageLabel`. It contains lot of letters then others, so it makes this gap to fit into `bfPercentageLabel`width.

But, this is not the gap I am expecting between the JLabels except `bfPercentageLabel`. If I remove that `bfPercentageLabel`, the spacing issue is gone, and it becomes normal, as the following image.

[image: This is the gap I want between these JLabels]

I want all the JLabels `heightLabel, weightLabel, waistLabel, neckLabel, hipsLabel` and JTextFields `heightTxt, weightTxt, waistTxt, neckTxt, hipsTxt` to stay in the same format, use the same spacing as shown in the second image, even though the width of `bfPercentageLabel` is more. Let the `bfPercentageLabel` to have the space it need but let other to stay as they are. How can I do this? Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your last label (the long one), simply add the following to the `GridBagConstraint`:

```
gbc.gridwidth = 6;
```

Comment: wow. That is awesome. Can you please explain it? I can remember I have used this sometime back, but without knowing it's original functionality. Do you mind explaining it please?

Comment: @Sepala When you use `GridBagLayout` you are actually defining a grid in your container. When you indicate `gridwidth` you define the column span of the implicit underlying cell. Therefore, before your label was stuck in a cell that could only span over the first column (resulting in the first column being very wide). With that new constraint, the cell spans over the 6 columns of your grid.